# How to open a wsl directory in git bash terminal

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to open this `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu` wsl directory in git bash terminal. My git bash terminal is currently open in `/c/Users/DELL` directory.

I tried `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu` pasting this command in the bash shell, but it throws error saying that `bash: \wsl.localhostUbuntu: No such file or directory` .

Can anybody help me opening that in git bash terminal.

Few days back i managed it to open that in git bash, see this image
[image]

But now I am unable to do so, don't know how I managed to do so earlier

Comment: Try this command: `cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu`

Comment: cd '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu' should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command:

```
cd //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu
```

The command `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu` didn't work, because

1. Bash removes backslashes while parsing the command (solution: use forward slashes: `/`).
2. You didn't indicate that you want to change the current directory, without that Bash interpreted your command as running an external program by that name (solution: use the `cd` command).